# How do I produce iterative equations and bifurcation diagrams?

Tags: iterators

I need to produce orbit diagrams for different values of x for the following equation:

```
f[r_][x_]:= r*x - x^3
```

I'm fairly new to *Mathematica*, so I haven't had a lot of practice using it. Basically I need to produce bifurcation diagrams for different values of `x`; then, using these plots, identify `r` values at which bifurcation occurs and determine the convergence ratio.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of help with the first stage...

```
f[r_,x_]:=r x-x^3;
```

To generate a bifurcation diagram...

```
ListPlot[
  Module[{x=0.5, n=1000},Apply[Join,Table[Thread[{r,NestList[f[r,#]&,x,n][[n/2;;-1]]}],{r,0,3,0.0125}]]], 
  Frame->True,Axes->False, ImageSize->600, PlotStyle->PointSize[Tiny]]
```

If you start reading up on the various functions used here you should be on your way at least.